# php exec not working from script but working from command line

Tags: php, exec

I try to execute command

```
convert -geometry x30 C:\xampp\htdocs\schuleweise\engine\Shopware\../../media/image\3573349700001A.jpg C:\xampp\htdocs\schuleweise\engine\Shopware\../../media/image\thumbnail\3573349700001A_30x30.jpg
```

Which works from command line, but not from the script with exec($command).
can anybody help me here ?

Comment: Those two versions of the php engine use separate configuration files (`php.ini`). Compare the settings.

Comment: apache might  not be the owner of the parent directory.. pls do check that

OR

apache's php.ini file may be disabling the use of exec().
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

Answer (score 0):

[`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) commands require full path to command in order to work in php.

Try it like this,

```
exec('usr/bin/convert -geometry x30 ..', $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to alternate function to exec()

```
system($shell_command, $response_var);
```

So in your case:

```
system("convert -geometry x30 C:\xampp\htdocs\schuleweise\engine\Shopware\../../media/image\3573349700001A.jpg C:\xampp\htdocs\schuleweise\engine\Shopware\../../media/image\thumbnail\3573349700001A_30x30.jpg", $output);
```